# How can i customize the lines of this canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I started to work on this animation and got the base from another animation, i have pretty much customized it all to my needs besides the lines. Currently the lines are pointy and i have gone through the code multiple times trying to find what creates these spiky lines. I would appreciate if someone could check both the provided code and the external code and identify what it is. All help is appreciated thanks.

```js
// Settings
var particleCount = 35,
flareCount = 0,
motion = 0.05,
tilt = 0,
particleSizeBase = 1,
particleSizeMultiplier = 0.5,
flareSizeBase = 100,
flareSizeMultiplier = 100,
glareAngle = -60,
glareOpacityMultiplier = 0.4,
renderParticles = true,
renderParticleGlare = true,
renderFlares = false,
renderLinks = false,
renderMesh = false,
flicker = false,
flickerSmoothing = 15, // higher = smoother flicker
blurSize = 0,
orbitTilt = true,
randomMotion = true,
noiseLength = 1000,
noiseStrength = 3;

document.querySelectorAll('.stars').forEach(canvas => {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  color = canvas.dataset['color'],
  mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 },
  m = {},
  r = 0,
  c = 1000, // multiplier for delaunay points, since floats too small can mess up the algorithm
  n = 0,
  nAngle = (Math.PI * 2) / noiseLength,
  nRad = 100,
  nScale = 1,
  nPos = {x: 0, y: 0},
  points = [],
  vertices = [],
  triangles = [],
  links = [],
  particles = [],
  flares = [];

  function init() {
    var i, j, k;

    // requestAnimFrame polyfill
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function( callback ){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();


    // Size canvas
    resize();

    mouse.x = canvas.clientWidth / 2;
    mouse.y = canvas.clientHeight / 2;

    // Create particle positions
    for (i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
      var p = new Particle();
      particles.push(p);
      points.push([p.x*c, p.y*c]);
    }


    vertices = Delaunay.triangulate(points);


    var tri = [];
    for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
      if (tri.length == 2) {
        triangles.push(tri);
        tri = [];
      }
      tri.push(vertices[i]);
    }


    // Tell all the particles who their neighbors are
    for (i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      // Loop through all tirangles
      for (j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++) {
        // Check if this particle's index is in this triangle
        k = triangles[j].indexOf(i);
        // If it is, add its neighbors to the particles contacts list
        if (k !== -1) {
          triangles[j].forEach(function(value, index, array) {
            if (value !== i && particles[i].neighbors.indexOf(value) == -1) {
              particles[i].neighbors.push(value);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }

    var fps = 60;
    var now;
    var then = Date.now();
    var interval = 1000/fps;
    var delta;
    // Animation loop
    (function animloop(){
      requestAnimFrame(animloop);
      now = Date.now();
      delta = now - then;
      if (delta > interval) {


        then = now - (delta % interval);

        resize();
        render();
      }

    })();
  }

  function render() {
    if (randomMotion) {
      n++;
      if (n >= noiseLength) {
        n = 0;
      }

      nPos = noisePoint(n);

    }



    if (renderParticles) {
      // Render particles
      for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
        particles[i].render();
      }
    }


  }

  function resize() {

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth * (window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
    canvas.height = canvas.width * (canvas.clientHeight / canvas.clientWidth);

  }



  // Particle class
  var Particle = function() {
    this.x = random(-0.1, 1.1, true);
    this.y = random(-0.1, 1.1, true);
    this.z = random(0,4);
    this.color = color;
    this.opacity = random(0.1,1,true);
    this.flicker = 0;
    this.neighbors = []; // placeholder for neighbors
  };
  Particle.prototype.render = function() {
    var pos = position(this.x, this.y, this.z),
    r = ((this.z * particleSizeMultiplier) + particleSizeBase) * (sizeRatio() / 1000),
    o = this.opacity;



    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.globalAlpha = o;
    context.beginPath();

    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

    if (renderParticleGlare) {
      context.globalAlpha = o * glareOpacityMultiplier;

      context.ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, r * 100, r, (glareAngle - ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength * motion)) * (Math.PI / 180), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fill();
      context.closePath();
    }

    context.globalAlpha = 1;
  };

  // Utils

  function noisePoint(i) {
    var a = nAngle * i,
    cosA = Math.cos(a),
    sinA = Math.sin(a),


    rad = nRad;
    return {
      x: rad * cosA,
      y: rad * sinA
    };
  }

  function position(x, y, z) {
    return {
      x: (x * canvas.width) + ((((canvas.width / 2) - mouse.x + ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength)) * z) * motion),
      y: (y * canvas.height) + ((((canvas.height / 2) - mouse.y + ((nPos.y - 0.5) * noiseStrength)) * z) * motion)
    };
  }

  function sizeRatio() {
    return canvas.width >= canvas.height ? canvas.width : canvas.height;
  }

  function random(min, max, float) {
    return float ?
    Math.random() * (max - min) + min :
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }


  // init
  if (canvas) init();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 0%, #000000 100%);
  height: 100%;
}

#stars {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ironwallaby/delaunay/master/delaunay.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.15/minified/require.js"></script>

<canvas id="Stars" class="stars" width="300" height="300" data-color="#fff"></canvas>
```

Comment: I ran your code snippet and it actually looks pretty good to me. Not spiky at all. Can you post a screen shot of what you're seeing?

Comment: @kshetline Sorry mabye i was not clear of what i meant, as you can see in the animation the lines are pointy in their design, i would like some way to make them  non pointy and just straight lines.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting spikes is the radius of the ellipse is too large so the ends are so small they look like points but it's just a small radius.

```
  context.ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, r * 100, r, (glareAngle - ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength * motion)) * (Math.PI / 180), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
```

After experimenting with different shapes like rect() and arc():

The code below instead of using ellipse uses a rotated rectangle.  Since the shape is different the algorithm for getting the angle you wanted will need more work but this code solves the problem of the pointy ends.

```
  //context.ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, r * 100, r, (glareAngle - ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength * motion)) * (Math.PI / 180), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.rotate((glareAngle - ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength * motion)) * (Math.PI / 180));
  context.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, r * 100, r)
  context.closePath();
```

It will take more work to align them to match the first code, but the pointy ends are gone.

Also, rotate() is actually rotating the canvas not the rectangles so keep that in mind. I would start with a simple 45 degree angle and see what that generates.

Comment: Thank you but i think you misunderstood what i was in need of. I am trying to make the design of the lines non "pointy" "spiky".. just straight lines.

Comment: i have updated my question with what i need help with.

Answer (score 0):

```
       // Tell all the particles who their neighbors are
for (i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
  // Loop through all tirangles
  for (j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++) {
    // Check if this particle's index is in this triangle
    k = triangles[j].indexOf(i);
    // If it is, add its neighbors to the particles contacts list
    if (k !== -1) {
      triangles[j].forEach(function(value, index, array) { // <----- missing ')' here
        if (value !== i && particles[i].neighbors.indexOf(value) == -1) {
          particles[i].neighbors.push(value);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i have updated my question with what i need help with.